# What's that text above the viewport?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, design

I was scrolling back up to the top of a page when I noticed this weird red text floating above the viewport in the "rubber-band-scroll" region. It says "Stack Exchange Inbox" and "Reputation and Badges."

[[Link to video]](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxRMbmixnUEocUZ1Q1ZFTDQ5M0E)

This doesn't occur on any other sites within the Stack Exchange network. The out-of-viewport "hidden text" only shows up on Programmers. So what's up with that?

This probably *isn't* for screen readers because there're already buttons on the top bar for those actions, and those have `alt` text.

Comment: could this text by chance read ["you're using unsupported browser"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/165773)?

Comment: @gnat, if that was the case, wouldn't the bug recreate on other sites within the Stack Exchange network? It might be due to an incomplete page-load. narawagames, can you recreate the bug after refreshing the website? Also, what browser are you on (just in case gnat is right).